# axios doesn't work on Samsung Tizen TVs but works fine in emulator

Tags: javascript, axios, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

simple axios works fine in emulator and browsers but doesn't work on Samsung Tizen TV 2016 and there is no error in console.

with using cdn:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

and script like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Tizen basic template generated by Tizen Web IDE"/>

    <title>Tizen Web IDE - Tizen - Samsung Tizen TV basic Application</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="width: 1920px; height:1080px; position: fixed;">

  <script>  
      axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/axios')
      .then(function(response){
      console.log(response.data);
      id = response.data.id;
      alert(id);
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think there can be only one reason why it cant work - Promises. Try to add polyfill https://github.com/axios/axios#promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved. there's a line of code that must be added to our script before using axios:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the privilege and the access policy in the `config.xml`

## Privilege

In order give the permission to access the network you need to set it in the tizen studio.

[image: Set Internet Privilege in tizen studio]

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/network.public"/>
```

## Policy

Hery you need set set which urls you can access.
[image]

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```